# Avoiding Brute Force: Counting Solutions

Tags: algorithm, brute-force, series

In a programming contest, a problem was:

> Count all solutions to the equation: `x + 4y + 4z = n`. You will be
>   given `n` and you will determine the count of solutions. Assume x, y and z are positive integers.

I have considered using triple for loops (brute force), but it was unefficient, causing TIME LIMIT EXCEED. (since the n may be = 1000,000):

```
int sol = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
{
 for (int j = 1; j <= n / 4; j++)
 {
  for (int k = 1; k <= n / 4; k++)
   {
      if (i + 4 * j + 4 * k == n)
         sol++;
   }
 }
}
```

My friend could solve the problem. When I asked him, he said that he didn't use brute force at all. Instead, he converted the equation to a 'series' (i.e. summition). I asked him to tell how me but he refused :)

Can I know how?

Comment: x, y and z often denote real numbers. Are they assumed to be integers here? Positive? Or also negative numbers?

Comment: Potentially useful: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation#Linear_Diophantine_equations

Comment: This equation defines a plane in R3, which contains an infinite number of integer solutions. You can't bruteforce an infinite set ;)

Comment: Most likely the missing constraint is that x, y and z are non-negative integers.

Comment: If that's the case (x, y, z are non-negative integers), could you use generating functions to solve this?

Comment: Wondering why 2 down votes for this question?

Comment: I would say Mathematics stackexchange to be an appropriate place for this question.

Comment: @yasouser, because they OP obviously left off key information.  Also the Q is off topic, probably belongs on http://math.stackexchange.com/ .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is particular case of [coin change problem](http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/Coin_Change), which is solved in general by dynamic programming.

But here we can elaborate simple solution. I consider x,y,z > 0

x + 4*(y+z)=n
Let y + z = q = p + 1 (q > 1, p > 0)

x+4*q=n

x+4*p=n-4

There are **M = Floor((n-5)/4)** variants for x and p, hence there are M possible values of 
q = 2..M+1
For every q>1 there are (q-1) variants of y and z: q = 1 + (q-1) = 2 + (q-2) +..+(q-1)+1

So we have **N**=1 + 2 + 3 + ... + M = **M * (M + 1)/2** solutions

Example:

n = 15;

M = (15 - 5) div 4 = 2

N = 3

(3,1,2),(3,2,1),(7,1,1)

Answer (score 1):

First note that `n-x` must be divisible by `4`. Start by finding the smallest value that `x` can take:

```
start = 4
while ((n - start) % 4 != 0)
{
    start = start + 1
}
```

From now on, you know that `x` will take values from `[start, start+4, start+8 ...]`. Now you can count the number of solutions by a simple counting loop:

```
count = 0

for (x = start; x < n - 4; x = x + 4)
{
    y_z_sum = (n - x) / 4
    count = count + y_z_sum - 1
}
```

For each choice of `x`, we can compute the value of `y+z`. For each value for `y+z`, there are `y+z-1` possible choices (since `y` ranges from 1 to `y+z-1`, assuming that `y` and `z` are both positive integers).

Instead of a brute force solution with O(n<sup>3</sup>) running time, you can achieve O(n) this way.

Comment: When tested with n = 40, Brute Force = 36 while this solution gives 45 ??

Comment: Why are your loops' tests are `<= n/4`? You are missing some solutions because your range is too small.

Comment: I am checking n/4 because the equation indicates that 4y = n. So, y can not be larger than n/4. The same is with z.

Comment: Right. Change the initial `start` value to `4` and it should work fine (edited the answer accordingly).

Comment: sorry. Still doesn't work. What if `n` % 4 != 0? for example: n = 432. Brute force = 5671 = this solution. When n = 479: Brute force = 5671, this solution = 5565.

Answer (score -1):

This is a classic linear algebra problem. Please refer to any linear algebra textbook on how to solve a system of linear equations. One such method is called [Gaussian Elimination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination).

Comment: @Down-voter: can you please give the reason as to why you have given a down vote?

Comment: Wasn't me, but Gaussian Elimination is useless here.  The "system of equations" is just one equation.